# How to intercept network from Android Application without Android Studio?

Tags: android, network-programming, httprequest, adb

I want to see the existing network traffic when running an Android application. My expectation is to get some components from HTTP Request such as endpoint URL, headers (if any), request body, and response body.

[image: example]

I've seen in some tutorials, that they use `adb` tool and Android Studio to be able to integrate Network Interceptor. Is it possible to do it only with `adb` tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have once used [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to intercept my physical device packets, it worked well with some apps but not all of them, I think that some apps implements some kind of an extra layer of security to prevent such a thing.
I have not tried it on the emulator.

`Edit:` To add to this answer, I think What Charles Proxy (or any intercepting app) is doing, is to stand in the middle of the streamline, between the server and the application, and receive the application's requests, log them, than reroute them to the server, receive the response back from the server and reroute it to the app. This technique is considered a security problem, known as `Man In the Middle Attack`, so some apps apply a security measure to prevent it, known as `Certificate Pinning` , which consists of :

> hard-coding a specific certificate or set of certificates into your
> app, ensuring that it only communicates with the intended server and
> not a malicious one that has been spoofed.

[Source](https://aamirchoksi.medium.com/securing-android-app-from-man-in-the-middle-attack-mitm-235ec223b8a8)

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Charles proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/) to see all api logs of your app. Also Charles is free of cost for normal use and it's great options for Mobile developers. I personally use it on emulator and physical device to debug logs that are hitting thought application.

Comment: Yes, and you can map local responses and other good to have features.

Comment: I have used Charles proxy, but It only shows hostname and hexa-string data. It cant show data like body requests or body responses.

Comment: I also spent lot of time to find the way to do this with adb command and also used Charles proxy before I knew and completely loved to use "mitm" tool which I recommended @Jordy in my other answer. mitm is one of the best one in my opionion in term of simplicity and efficiency.

Comment: @LocHuynh Thanks for your time, Can you give some examples of using mitm tool?

Comment: I followed and learned it from this link of https://gaikwadchetan93.medium.com/monitoring-modifying-android-app-network-traffic-via-mitm-proxy-part-1-886f6324f705

Comment: And https://youtu.be/XdTQ9-7ymYw for unpinning for any apk for study purpose

Comment: It was also the video I watched when I started to learn about mitm, you can start from here https://youtu.be/ktNUs4KdcZk

Comment: @LocHuynh Thanks btw, `mitmproxy` work successfully. But some apps have extra layer security so it will get hard to intercept it.

Comment: Yes, some apps you need to unpin thier apk files as I mentioned above. For study purpose, you can download and unpin thier older apk version.

Comment: @LocHuynh Ok. Thanks for recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is hard by using adb command only. it is posible and more easier to do that in term of GUI like developer console and batch mode by using the tool called `mitm`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Chucker Library](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker). It is straightforward to integrate. They also provide release implementation to hide this in the release build.

[Chucker sample](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker/blob/main/assets/chucker-http.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) by Meta. It supports Network and many other useful extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest tool to use is Proxyman (https://proxyman.io/), but the free version has a limited number of features. It has a nice interface and automatically installs certificates.

Personally, I prefer using MITMproxy (https://mitmproxy.org/), which is free, open source, and a very powerful tool. You can write custom scripts in python for MITMproxy or make use of scripts available on GitHub (https://github.com/KevCui/mitm-scripts).